# Filter Text by Lines

Tags: string-manipulation

For a string like

```
str = "This is a multi-line
string with
three lines total";
```

is there a way to search and filter it by lines so that

```
searchLines[str, "line"]
```

returns

```
This is a multi-line
three lines total
```

?

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like:

```
ClearAll[searchLines];
searchLines[text_,search_]:=StringJoin@Riffle[StringCases[
    StringSplit[text,"\n"],
    ___~~search~~___
]/.{}->Nothing,"\n"];
```

Try on your case:

```
searchLines[str, "line"]
```

> ```
> "This is a multi-line
> three lines total"
> ```

Comment: Is there a way to add a paramater `linesAround : NumberQ` to the function that shows `linesAround` lines above and `linesAround` lines below the matching results?  Sort of the like the `-c` option in `grep`?

Comment: @George I have not looked at `grep` that much but can you give an explicit example of the output?

Comment: Sure. `searchLines[str, "string", 1]` on the `str` above should return `str` itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "This is a multi-line
  string with
  three lines total";

fn = StringDelete["[]\n"]@*
   StringReplace[RegularExpression["(?m)^^((?!line).)*$$"] :> "[]"];

fn[str]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the `"Lines"` element for `ImportString`/`ExportString`.

```
filterLines[str_, patt_] :=
 ExportString[
  Select[
   ImportString[str, "Lines"],
   StringContainsQ[patt]],
  "Lines"]

filterLines[str, "line"]
(* 
"This is a multi-line
three lines total"
*)
```

## Update

As Suba Thomas pointed out in comments, the `ImportString`/`ExportString` slows things down a lot. Using `StringSplit` and `StringRiffle` to perform the task is much faster:

```
filterLinesFaster[str_, patt_] :=
 StringRiffle[
  Select[StringSplit[str, "\n"], StringContainsQ[patt]],
  "\n"]    

First@RepeatedTiming[filterLines[str, "line"]]/
 First@RepeatedTiming[filterLinesFast[str, "line"]]
(* 9.*10^1 *)
```

However, when I tried this on a much longer string, the speed difference shrinks considerably:

```
SeedRandom[1337];
superStr =
  StringRiffle[
   RandomChoice[
    StringSplit[str, "\n"],
    {1000}],
   "\n"];

First@RepeatedTiming[filterLines[superStr, "line"]]/
 First@RepeatedTiming[filterLinesFast[superStr, "line"]]
(* 3.2 *)
```

Still slower than the "fast" solution (not to mention Suba's and user13892's approaches, which are faster still), but it's interesting how much it shrinks. I think `ImportString` and `ExportString` may set up temporary files or streams to work with, which may add a substantial constant time to the task.

Anyway, I've used the `ImportString`/`ExportString` pair a **lot** in my own code to turn strings to lists of lines and back, and, well, I won't do that anymore!

Comment: But it's rather slow?

Comment: Is it? Didn't benchmark.

Comment: Benchmarking with [`RepeatedTiming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedTiming.html), shows this solution is ~150x slower than mine and ~120x slower than that of user13892.

Comment: Thanks for going the extra mile and the additional analysis.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work too:

```
StringDelete[str, RegularExpression["(?m)^(?!.+line).*\n"]]
```